# Allow Multiple Boxes for shipping 1 product

Tags: magento2, shipping, fedex, carrier

In our Magento store we have some products which weigh more than 150lbs. For such product FedExs shipping is not available on checkout page as FedEx does not allow weight more than 150 lbs for single box. If I reduce weight to below 150, FedEx appears in the shipping methods.

These products can be shipped in Multiple boxes so I set  **Allow Multiple Boxes for Shipping** to **Yes** for those products under **Advance Inventory** pop up.

Still FedEx is not calculating shipping price for these products. How can I allow multiple box shipping for these products For FedEx Shipping?